# Can Bootstrap be customized?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand that the essence of Bootstrap is to create responsive design using templates that can be downloaded from the site. Can we apply our creativity to design our own layout in Bootstrap, similar to what can be achieved using Adobe Dreamweaver (HTML and CSS)?
Kindly provide some directions, if that is possible.

Comment: All of these were made in Bootstrap. http://expo.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: After the four given answers is any more information you still need? If one of the answers is adequate and useful to you you can accept it with the green arrow.  Any other answers that helped you should usually be upvoted as well, although that requires 15 reputation and so you are not yet able to do so. If you still need something answered or explained, you can edit your question or pose new ones depending on your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, I haven't use Adobe Dreamweaver but I assume that your desired output is **HTML** and **CSS** and that **you have enough knowledge about it**.

Bootstrap actually uses html for elements and CSS for designs (plus javascript for behaviors).

Check the following snippet:

```css
.custom-design {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  color: black !important;
  border: 3px black solid !important;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is the default primary button of Bootstrap:</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
    
    <p>This is the default primary button which I overrode the design:</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary custom-design">Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am merely saying just like a designer can create a website using Adobe Dreamweaver (using HTML and CSS), can we do the same thing (to create) with Bootstrap? Do we need to manipulate the HTML and CSS to achieve the same? I intend to make use of Bootstrap to create Responsive Design, not Dreamweaver. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Every bootstrap template was designed by someone. Bootstrap is just some CSS, and Javascript and they give you the code. When you say "the essence of Bootstrap is to create responsive design using templates that can be downloaded from the site", I don't think this is really correct, or fair to Bootstrap and the people who use it. A lot of people use bootstrap in this way, and there's nothing wrong with that, but it's quite limiting to have to just pick from a list of templates and stick with it. The templates are going to be designed to meet the needs of as many people as possible, and so they are not necessarily optimal for your specific needs. A lot of them are often close however, and will just need some basic modifications to get to where you want them. Luckily, tools like bootstrap, or polymer, am more material alternative rarely work this way.

Bootstrap isn't just a collection of templates, it is a collection of components, including buttons, icons, headers, menus, inputs, and more. Here are the components [on bootstrap's website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/). You can make your own templates by combining the components the way you would combine your own components if you were working from scratch. Furthermore, when you download bootstrap, you get the source code, and so you can customize the components as well to get even more control. Even this view of Bootstrap is in a way limiting because Bootstrap also has a sizable Javascript API allowing it to be a starting point (or perhaps a complete solution if your needs are fully met) for customizing behaviors, including transitions, sizing, event handling, and again, much more.

If you do a google search for customizing Bootstrap you can find plenty of examples, as well as some tools designed to make it easier. If you need a good resource for learning bootstrap basics (the CSS, Javascript, and the components) just use their main website, the documentation is pretty good.

If you want to simply code the webpage with HTML and CSS (or whatever your choice of language is for front-end web design, the documentation is plenty. If you want to generate a basic template, you can also look into Bootstrap's own generator for custom themes [found here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). I have not personally used it, but it seems quite straight forward.

The templates are really just there to make things easy, and usually if you use one you are going to want to customize pieces of it anyways to optimize it for your content. If you like front-end design, making your own themes is a great option. If you are more interested in the content, or backend logic of a site, and the tediousness of designing a theme from scratch sounds like more work then you would like to deal with, you can use a prebuilt theme, and perhaps customize it a bit with your own preferences. Things made in bootstrap will often have a certain consistent look to it, but you are not limited to the handful of prebuilt options on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my way can help to give you some direction or an idea. 
You can use any kind of front-end Javascript framework (like Bootstrap / Angular etc), to make a template very easily and quickly, however it might waste too much time. If I were you, I would use a template and then mix my own idea to create a new template for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's just css and/or JavaScript.